# construct a function with embed r code in rpy2

Tags: embed, rpy2, suppress-warnings

I want to suppress warning. But the following code does not suppress warnings.

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects

kstest=robjects.r['ks.test']

suppressWarnings=robjects.r['suppressWarnings']

x=robjects.IntVector([1, 2, 3])
y=robjects.IntVector([1, 2, 4, 5])

result=suppressWarnings(kstest(x, y))
print result
print result[1][0]
```

If I can construct a function like in rpy2 and call the function instead, I think that the warning can be suppressed.

```
f=function(x, y) {
    suppressWarnings(kstest(x, y))
}
```

But I don't find examples in rpy2 document. Does anybody have some examples?

Answer (score 0):

When doing in rpy2 `suppressWarnings(kstest(x, y))`, the call `kstest(x, y)` is first evaluated (and is generating warnings), then the result returned is passed to `suppressWarnings()`.

What is happening is that R's `suppressWarning()` silences warnings generated by the call passed as an argument. This is possible because in R the parameters are only evaluated when they are needed in the body of the function; a notable difference with Python.

The way to mimic that with rpy2 would be to construct an unevaluated call an pass it to `suppressWarning()`, or as you suggest push the call to R and create an R function that will wrap the call. The documentation shows how to [evaluate a string as R code](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.3/html/robjects_rinstance.html#evaluating-a-string-as-r-code), with an example with a function.